# Alsa: Creating a virtual microphone

Tags: linux, audio, virtual, microphone, alsa

How can I correctly change a .asoundrc file to realize a virtual microphone?

I have the follow .asoundrc file, but it doesn't work:

```
pcm.audinp {
        type file
        slave.pcm front
        file /dev/null
        infile /writable/home/user/virtualmic.pipe
        format "raw"
}

pcm.!default {
        type plug
        slave.pcm "audinp"
}
```

Comment: This question seems like a dup to me. See my answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4580986/simulate-microphone-virtual-mic